# CodeArtifact Unlisted External Repositories

Tags: maven, aws-codeartifact, clojars

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/external-connection.html lists public repos that can be added as external repositories.

How can I add an unlisted repo to my CodeArtifact, e.g. Clojars?

Note:

- Clojars for humans: https://clojars.org
- Clojars packages: https://repo.clojars.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, CodeArtifact does not support connecting to arbitrary public repositories which are not on the list you mention.

That said, if you give that page a refresh you'll now find Clojars on the supported list!

Comment: This will save us a ton of work. Thank you!